# Ice Maker Not Filling Fully or Dumping Ice - Supply Issue?

Tags: ice-maker

I have a new Frigidaire Gallery, bottom mount, fridge with a built-in water dispenser and ice maker.

I installed the water line about a month ago, it's only a single water line running to the fridge. So the water dispenser and ice maker run off the same source (one connection on the fridge). I tapped into the kitchen sink's cold water supply.

When I installed it, it immediately began making tiny ice cubes, which I thought was annoying but decided it must be "normal" since it was the first cubes it made. It filled the entire ice compartment with these small cubes (about 0.5" cubes). Then it didn't make any more ice, ever. I didn't notice it stopped making ice because I rarely ever use ice in the early spring, but the buffer ran out and I'm noticing it's not making any.

The cubes it made were not hollow, they were solid little ice cubes. So it is possible that they are the correct size.

There are some frozen cubes up in the tray (I felt in there for them), but it is not releasing them. Perhaps they are too small.

When I use the water dispenser, it seems to be fast, much faster than my old fridge.
So, I don't think there's a problem with my supply line.
...but how to I verify that there's no problem with my supply line?

It takes about 10s to fill a glass, which I thought was pretty good, because it's about as fast as my kitchen sink.

When searching through issues with ice makers I am seeing a lot of problems with slow water supply causing an ice maker to fail. However, honestly, how much water pressure does the ice maker need? Is it a big problem if it takes 10, 20, or even 30 seconds to fill the tray? Do most ice makers meter water based on time? That just seems wrong. What if the tray is filling while I'm using the kitchen sink?

This might seem like a lot of questions, but the bottom line is "How do I verify my supply line is good enough to feed my ice maker?".

Comment: Sounds to me like the ice maker is defective and probably was from day 1.

Comment: I'm okay with that, but I need to prove that the supply line is good. Does it sound like my water flow is acceptable?

Comment: If it's filling a glass as fast as your faucet does, I'd say that proves the supply line is fine. An ice maker doesn't require a huge amount of water pressure. Mine works just fine off a well that provides 30-50 psi, which is lower than most municipal water systems.

Comment: @CareyGregory The caveat to that remark is that my faucet is almost abnormally aerated, so it doesn't fill a glass all that fast at all, compared to say... the laundry tub. I don't know what pressure the supply line is providing, only the fill rate coming out of the dispenser.

Comment: Well, I still don't think pressure is the issue. I think you have a defective ice maker. Since the refrigerator is new I would consult the people you bought it from and raise a warranty issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to "reset the fridge"...

So, apparently there was a power outage or something like that while the ice maker was making ice, so the fridge lost it's marbles.

The solution to this problem was the "reset" the fridge.

Go into the menu, find the "default settings" option, and hold "set" till it beeps.

I have no idea why this performs a reset, we *are* and *always were* using the factory default settings, and turning the "make ice" option off, and on again apparently can not cause this reset to happen.

The ice cubes are supposed to be tiny, and apparently even ice makers need to be "reset" every now and then.